# How to properly time an ocaml program?

Tags: unix, ocaml

```
let t = Unix.gettimeofday()
let rec nothing i =
  match i with
  | 1000000000 -> 1
  | _ -> nothing (i+1)
let () = Printf.printf "%d %fs\n" (nothing 0) (Unix.gettimeofday() -. t)
```

I use the command

```
ocamlc unix.cma test.ml
```

to compile it to bytecode. The execution time is apparently several seconds, but the program prints 0.000001s.

And if I replace Unix.gettimeofday() with Sys.time(), it is just 0.000000s.

Running the code in `utop` is not much better. It gives about 0.02s, while I count at least 5s.

I am wondering what goes wrong here? I am on Debian Wheezy and ocaml version is 4.02.1.

Comment: Are you sure `Unix.gettimeofday()` is evaluated before `nothing 0`? I don’t know OCaml, but it doesn’t look like it is at all.

Comment: why not? I believe it is eagerly evaluated.

Comment: As @ivg says, evaluation order of function arguments is *unspecified*. Eagerness is about whether they are evaluated before the call, not about the order.

Comment: I see. I thought the previous poster was referring to `let t = Unix.gettimeofday()`.

Comment: For execution timings also have a look at `val Unix.times : unit -> process_times` which gives you data like the unix time utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments to printf function, as well as to any other function are evaluated in an unspecified order. In your case the `(Unix.gettimeofday () -. t)` expression is evaluated before the the `(nothing 0)`. A more proper version of the code would be:

```
let rec nothing i =
  match i with
  | 1000000000 -> 1
  | _ -> nothing (i+1)


let () =
  let t = Unix.gettimeofday() in 
  Printf.printf "%ds\n" (nothing 0);
  Printf.printf "time elapsed: %g s\n" (Unix.gettimeofday() -. t)
```