# slow byte code with tail recursion

Tags: recursion, ocaml, performance-testing, tail-recursion

Inspired by the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652007/how-to-properly-time-an-ocaml-program) I took the code to check an imperative loop against tail recursion:

```
let rec nothingfunc i =
  match i with
  | 1000000000 -> 1
  | _ -> nothingfunc (i+1)

let nothingloop1 () =
  let i = ref 0 in
   while !i < 1000000000 do incr i done;
   1

let timeit f v =
  let t1 = Unix.gettimeofday() in
  let _ = f v in
  let t2 =  Unix.gettimeofday() in
    t2 -. t1

let () =
  Printf.printf "recursive function: %g s\n%!" (timeit nothingfunc 0);
  Printf.printf "while loop with ref counter buitin incr: %g s\n%!" (timeit nothingloop1 ());
```

For bytecode and native code the results are

```
str@s131-intel:~> ./bench_loop
recursive function: 20.7656 s
while loop with ref counter buitin incr: 12.0642 s
str@s131-intel:~> ./bench_loop.opt 
recursive function: 0.755594 s
while loop with ref counter buitin incr: 0.753947 s
```

The question is: what is the reason for the big difference 20 to 12  seconds execution time?

**Edit, my conclusion:**

A function call `apply` (in byte code) involves a stack size check, possible stack enlargement, and a check for signals. For maximum performance the native code compiler will deliver.

(Side note: asking here on SO because it is search engine friendly.)

Comment: opt in ocamlopt stands for optimized. Bytecode compiler performs less optimizations, as it wasn't ever its purpose. Although many optimizations are still done. And, for example, on current version of the compiler (4.03) the difference is about 10% (9.3 vs 8.3 seconds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at the output of `ocamlfind ocamlc -package unix test.ml -dlambda`

```
(nothingloop1/1010 =
     (function param/1022
       (let (i/1011 =v 0)
         (seq (while (< i/1011 100000000) (assign i/1011 (1+ i/1011))) 1)))

(nothingfunc/1008
   (function i/1009
     (if (!= i/1009 100000000) (apply nothingfunc/1008 (+ i/1009 1)) 1)))
```

So apparently `assign` is faster than `apply`. There seems to be checks for stack overflows and signals at function invocations, but not for a simple assign. For details, you have to look at: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/byterun/interp.c

Comment: Okay, found it. This looks like a Forth interpreter.